# Позиционирование блока в блоке

Tags: html, css, javascript

Ниже представлен готовый тестовый пример (html-страничка), просто рядом с ней положить jquery.js и запустить.

В этом примере блок **#h-phones** помещается в самую правую часть блока **#header-block**, учитывая отступы последнего... Здесь всё правильно. НО когда мы начинаем уменьшать размер окна браузера - блок **#h-phones** "уходит" вправо -- ПОЧЕМУ?

*ведь **#header-block** в % и отступ слева для **#h-phones** в процентах...*

Для теста скопируйте и запустите следующий код (рядом положить jquery.js):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="nojs" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
header{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #999999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
#header-block{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border:1px dotted #FFF;
    height:120px
}
#header-block:before,
#header-block:after{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
#header-block:after{
    clear: both;
}
#h-phones ul{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#logo, #alogo, #slogan, #h-phones {
    clear: left;
    cursor: move;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
            //все левые отступы #header-block + левый бордюр
        HBbbb = parseFloat(parseFloat($("#header-block").css('margin-left')) + parseFloat($("#header-block").css('padding-left')) + parseFloat($("#header-block").css('border-left-width')));           
        HBwidth = $("#header-block").width(); //ширина #header-block        
        HPwidth = $("#h-phones").width(); //ширина нужного блока

        //для теста - просто "приклеить" блок к правому краю
        lleft = HBwidth - HPwidth + HBbbb; //отступ в px
        pleft = parseFloat((lleft / (HBwidth + (HBbbb*2))) * 100);  //отступ в процентах

        //Двигаем:
        $("#header-block").css('position','relative');
        $("#h-phones").css({'position':'absolute','top':0,'left':pleft+'%'});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap-header">
<header>
<div id="header-block">

        <div id="h-phones">
            <ul><li>1-800-45-PEACH</li><li>1-800-45-PEACH</li><li>1-800-45-PEACH</li></ul>
        </div>

</div>                      
</header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вот пример на jsfiddle.net
http://jsfiddle.net/N7Ftx/

Comment: а как вы хотели ? он же вправо уходит своей **левой границей** которая установлена в ~75%. так хотелось ? http://jsfiddle.net/N7Ftx/1/

Comment: так уже и сделал http://jsfiddle.net/N7Ftx/3/
спасибо, что откликнулись